# python social auth change referrer address

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I have an Azure Application Gateway (lets say example.com), behind which I have a few Azure App Services (example1.com, example2.com, etc).

I am using python social auth to authenticate my django app. The issue is that when I click login from example.com, and it forwards that request to example1.com, the login request happens from example1.com.

If I specify a OAuth callback addresses as

> example.com/complete/azuread-oauth2,
>
> example1.com/complete/azuread-oauth2, and
>
> example2.com/complete/azuread-oauth2,

it doesn't work, social auth gives me the error:

```
raise AuthStateForbidden(self)
social_core.exceptions.AuthStateForbidden: Wrong state parameter given.
```

This might be because of the referrer site being example.com, but the actual request going from example1.com, though I am not sure. Is there any way to fix it so that the redirection doesnt happen to example1.com, and I can hide example1.com behind example.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python-social-auth` Django strategy uses [`request.build_absolute_uri(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method, which depends on [`request.get_host(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) in order to retrieve the current host the URL should be point to.

When your setups is behind a proxy (or behaves like that), you need to ensure that the destination server knows the originating host source in order to setup the proper URL. Check the `get_host()` documentation, it lists the different options that must be set to make that possible.

Comment: Thanks Omab! I set the USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST setting in django and changed the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST header, and it worked! The App Service was removing the header from the Azure Gateway for some reason, so I had to hardcode the host name, but atleast it works now.

Comment: This still fails when I run django with Debug=False. Trying to figure out why that is