# Django social-auth: How to handle Youtube (Google) Auth Error: AuthStateForbidden?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, youtube-api, python-social-auth

I am using django social-auth to authorize users in Google Analytics and Youtube. Hence one backend in 2 different templates is used. However, with Google Analytics everything works like charm, but when I try to authorize in Youtube in the end of the authentication process comes an error:

> social_core.exceptions.AuthStateForbidden: Wrong state parameter given.

I have tried to remove already successfully authorized my app for Google Analytics Scopes from Google Account and authorize again for Youtube Scopes but it brings no difference.

My youtube handler:

```
class YouTubeLoginHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, client_secret):
        self.SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
        self.CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = client_secret

    def init_youtube_api(self):
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            os.path.abspath(
                os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
            ), scopes=self.SCOPES)


        flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/'

        authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
            # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
            access_type='offline',
            # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
            include_granted_scopes='true')

        return authorization_url
```

My view in views.py

```
@login_required
def login_youtube(request):
    user = request.user
    youtube = YouTubeLoginHandler('client_secrets.json')
    authorization_url = youtube.init_youtube_api()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorization_url)
```

Comment: which type of client did you create on google developer console?

Comment: @DaImTo OAuth 2.0 Client

Comment: yes but which type,  service account, web application, desktop app?

Comment: @DaImTo aah ok, well of Web application, I used this manual https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

Comment: isnt from_client_secrets_file designed for installed applications?

Comment: @DaImTo well the client_secret file was also created after creation of creds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python social auth change referrer address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252061/python-social-auth-change-referrer-address)

Comment: @DaImTo I have already checked this one, but I have just one host, not really apllies to my case